# C++ Best Way Of Outputting Formatted Variable Argument Lists

Tags: c++, debugging, cout, variadic-functions

This is my current function which works but is not type safe and can get annoying sometimes.

```
void Debug::Log(LogLevel level, const char* format, ...)
{
va_list args;
va_start(args, format);
cout << "[" << LogLevelToString(level) << "]\t";
vprintf(format, args);
va_end(args);
cout << endl;
}
```

As you can see I would like for the arguments passed in to be formatted by the format specified. I know std::cout has formatting capabilities but I haven't found anything which explains how it can be implemented with the C va_list.

Basically the main points are: I want to keep the the same behavior but with a type safe more modern method, I need to std::cout so I can easily redirect output to file or where ever I need to.

Helpful points: from the format I can determine how many parameters where passed in, is there a way to loop through va_list arguments so I can pass them to cout individually?

Thanks

Comment: You can use variadic templates to implement a typesafe `printf`.

Comment: Well I just edited the question a bit. I want to use only std::cout so I only have to manage that when i want to redirect the output to a file or where ever. I don't really want to touch stdout(both cout and printf). I'm trying to stay away from c functions.

Comment: My point is that you can keep the syntax for calling it that you have now and make it typesafe by replacing the C varargs with a variadic template.

Comment: Does gcc support C++ 11 features? I'm also trying to keep this multi platform

Comment: Yes, many. Here's a [list](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) of them. Variadic templates were supported as of GCC 4.3.

Comment: You may want to take a look at how Boost format works.

Answer (score 0):

For easy redirection, you can certainly use `vfprintf()`. For individual control/cout of each argument, I think the only way is to `va_arg()` through the list using the correct type, i.e. `an_int = va_arg(the_va_list, int);`, `a_double = va_arg(the_va_list, double);`, and so on. I haven't tried but I think `va_arg` will do the proper increment on the memory using the `type` passed to it.

Comment: You can't do anything in a typesafe way with a va_list.